# nodeValue vs value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so i have this HTML web page with nothing fancy on it right? The problem is that when I try to place an image on the screen without using CSS (with the traditional < img > tag), I get this error in FireFox:

> Use of attributes' nodeValue attribute is deprecated. Use value instead.

The image display is simple, just the tag and the src.

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="administration/stylesheet.css">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<img src="administration/graphics/textlogo.png">
</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone knows what to do, cause I can't seem to find a solution.

Cheers!

Comment: could you post the code you are using?

Comment: MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeValue . I was looking for it but I can't find; I've experienced this before, I think it is some internal script/addon that uses it.

Comment: I don't really know why the error comes up eighter... but I've noticed that it is showed to me on almost every website I visit :|  And last night the error wasn't showing at all... it only started this morning on the very same code...

Comment: I would definitly go for some AddOn error ... Indeed, nothing's wrong in your code.

Comment: That very comforting, thanks a lot for your help folks.

Comment: In firefox (not in chrome) there is an indication of the error location on the right side of the error message. Just click on it and check where the error is coming from.